# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am beginner in Android Studio. I am trying to run my app on my mobile, but when i try to run my application on my mobile it shows

> Unfortunately app has been stopped

Here is the error showed in Logcat android monitor.

```
10-23 23:19:25.882 18014-18014/com.example.dhara.codesprint E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dhara.codesprint, PID: 18014
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

{com.example.dhara.codesprint/com.example.dhara.codesprint.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
at com.example.dhara.codesprint.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Below is the code for MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dhara.codesprint;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
    TextView text5;
    TextView text6;
    EditText text7;
    Button checkAnswer;
    Button reset;

    //private WordDictionary dictionary;
    private String currentWord;
    private ArrayList<String> words;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("words.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Could not load dictionary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        text6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        text7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        checkAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });



        checkAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }





}
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dhara.codesprint">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Codesprint"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView3" />

    <EditText
        android:text="Your Answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView5"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView6"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView1"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <Button
        android:text="Check Your Answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Reset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried some solution from web but it is not working.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You layout does not have a `Toolbar`, and yet you are calling the following:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Either remove these calls or add a `Toolbar` to your layout.

For the latter to work you also need to use (or derive from) one of the AppCompat themes that do not have an `ActionBar`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` for example.

So in your *styles.xml* you would have something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initiate your view elements (TextView, Buttons etc) before setting out the layout xml which for your case is `R.layout.activity_main` file.

```
package com.example.dhara.codesprint;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //private WordDictionary dictionary;
    private String currentWord;
    private ArrayList<String> words;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView text6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        TextView text7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        Button checkAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("words.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Could not load dictionary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }


        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });



        checkAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize your layouts element in onCreate() because when your activity get start it calls onCreate() method ,but here you are calling your layout from your onCreate() method but after that you are not initializing your elements ,also check that whether you have added the name of activity in your manifest or not ,please read and implement carefully ,hope it ll help you.